# Problem In Sending Email Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hi every one i have use this code for sending email and i import header file and frame work to my app it works fine but i cannot receive email ?

```
-(IBAction)sendEmail :(id)sender
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setSubject: @""];
    [controller setMessageBody:@" " isHTML:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {

    NSLog(error);
    [self becomeFirstResponder];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code, not your question. Also, you are logging the error wrong. Do this instead: `NSLog(@"%@", error);`. You can probably not receive empty emails. **Have you looked in your spam folder?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to check:

- Did you test `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` first? Maybe, for some reason, your device is not able to send email
- Connected to the first point, are you running this on a device or on the Simulator? There may be differences
- Do you have email set up correctly on your device?
- Have you checked your spam folder?
- Is the error variable defined in the `didFinishWithResult:` method? That's an important detail that you didn't mention in your question

In summary, you need to give more information before anyone can reasonably answer this question.